# Any reason why a <ContextProvider> HOC won't change it's default value?

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

```
export const FocusContext = React.createContext({
    isUsingMouse: true,
    setIsUsingMouse: () => {
        console.error("FocusContext.Provider value not initialized");
    },
});

export const FocusContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isUsingMouse, setIsUsingMouse] = React.useState(true);

    return (
        <FocusContext.Provider value={{ isUsingMouse, setIsUsingMouse }}>
            {children}
        </FocusContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Aside from this file and it's instantiation near the root of the app, most files just import and `useContext(FocusContext)`

For some reason, the value is never taking effect, and `setIsUsingMouse` logs the defaultValue error

Is there any reason why this implementation of context as a HOC won't work?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this method works perfectly well.

The issue was that our `<ContextProvider>` wasn't being used in our Storybook, rather an outer integration layer (to interface with the mother app)